# Difficulty in binding JSON data to Jquery Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, datatables

I am having difficulty in binding JSON data to constuct a data table.

My JSON is of the following:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Number": "2",
    "Name": "Avinash"
  },
  {
    "ID":2,
    "Number":"21",
    "Name":"XYZ"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Number": "20",
    "Name": "KRR"
  }
]
```

I am binding this to jquery datatable as below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table_id').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '<%:Url.Action("LoadData","Home")%>'
            });
            $('#table_id').css("width", "100%")
        });
```

My Table Structure is as follows:

```
<table id="table_id" border="0" class="display" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center">
 <thead>           
            <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
```

I am getting error as follows:

```
  Datatables Warning(tableid="table_id"):Requested Unknown Parameter'0' from the datasource for row 0
```

please help..

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
                {
                    var Data = new DataTable();
                    Data=DataModel.LoadData();
                    var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.None);
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        aaData = JsonData
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a short investigation, since your JSON is objects, you should supply the columns definition -

json:

```
{ "aaData": [
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Number": "2",
    "Name": "Avinash"
  },
  {
    "ID":2,
    "Number":"21",
    "Name":"XYZ"
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Number": "20",
    "Name": "KRR"
  }
]}
```

js:

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
     "bProcessing": true,
     "sAjaxSource": '<%:Url.Action("LoadData","Home")%>',
     "aoColumns": [
                  { "mData": "ID" },
                  { "mData": "Number" },
                  { "mData": "Name" }
               ]
      });
```

See example in datatables source under ajax/objects.html.

Comment: No..Both of the syntaxes are correct..still i am getting that error. I am able to hit that controller action

Comment: Does your json include { "aaData": [ ... ? The above code is working for me for a static json url.

Comment: How do i append to my JSON if it is not there?

Comment: string withData = string.Format(@"{{ ""aaData"" : {0} }}", withoutData);  ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38895/discussion-between-kgu87-and-avinash)